# Passing class function using function pointer to external library

Tags: function, class, pointers, arduino

I have a class that uses a preexisting library. There is a function call that needs a function pointer, and I am trying to pass in the function that is in my class.  It doesn't compile though.  What can I do to fix this?  (Also, I'm sure this was asked before in a much clearer way.  I'm out of my element with this, so my apologies).
Note: This is for an arduino.

In my main program I have the following code...

```
#include "CM.h"

CM cm;

void setup()  {
    cm.setup();
}
```

CM.h

```
class CM {
    private:
        LibClass *lib;
        void onInit();

    public:
        void setup();
};
```

CM.cpp

```
#include "CM.h"

void CM::setup() {
    lib->attach(onInit);  // <-- this isn't working.
}

void CM::onInit() {
    Serial.println("HERE I AM");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a member function, you need to make it "static"  and then pass it with a full scope qualifier:

```
    #include <iostream>

    void attach( void (*func)(void) );


    class CM {
    private:
     static void onInit();

    public:
        void setup();
    };

    void CM::setup()
    {
        attach(CM::onInit);
    }

    void CM::onInit(void)
    {
        std::cout << "HERE I AM";
    }

    // a global function pointer for this example
    void (*p_func)(void);

   // a "library" attach function
    void attach( void (*func)(void) )
    {
        p_func = func;

    }


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        CM my;

        my.setup();

        p_func();  // like the library call 

        return 0;
    }
```